# Upgrade angular 7 to 8 successful, but core can't find module rxjs?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, single-page-application

I upgraded angular 7.X to angular 8.2.5. This is successful, and my application still runs. However, the `angular/core` module throws errors, claiming it cannot find `rxjs`. My version of `rxjs` is 6.5.3, which is brand new as of this writing.I have uninstalled `rxjs-compat` and reran `npm install` but the behavior did not change.

[image: error on ngserve]

(Text version for google searches:)

```
ERROR in ../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:8:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.

8 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
                             ~~~~~~
../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/event_emitter.d.ts:8:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.

8 import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
                                        ~~~~~~
../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/query_list.d.ts:8:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.

8 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
                             ~~~~~~
../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts:8:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.

8 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Subsequent compiles yield a similar but more compact error. For now, this does not seem to impact my application, it still runs.

[image]

What actions can I try to get rid of this error?

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp-ng",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-prettyjson": "^3.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "ngx-sortablejs": "^3.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "npm": "^6.10.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "sortablejs": "^1.10.0-rc3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "uninstall": "0.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

EDIT: I found the issue. There was rogue node_modules directory somewhere on ../../../../../ (which was clearly in the error logs mentioned above, but didn't seem suspicious considering the nested nature of npm projects). I don't know why or how but this directory was scanned and spewed errors - this explains why the app was running fine, because the node_modules directory in my project was just fine. I have deleted this rogue node_modules directory and the errors are now gone.

Comment: Have you tried deleting `node_modules` before running `npm install`?

Comment: @jpavel Deleting node_modules and doing a fresh npm install solved some random other (unrelated) warnings I had, but this error is still there.

Comment: I've upgraded a project of mine (just to test) to the versions you mentioned in your post without any problem. What do you get with `ng --version`?

Comment: did you check if there is rxjs folder in node_modules?

Comment: I would like to see your `package.json` file and your `tsconfig.json` files.

Comment: @jpavel if I run it in command prompt, not in my project folder, I get angular cli = 7.3.8 & rxjs 6.3.3 - not what I was expecting! The output of npm install shows me different numbers: angular 8.2.5 and rxjs 6.3.5

Comment: @jpavel if I run that command in my project folder, I do see angular cli 8.3.3 and angular 8.2.5!

Comment: @Reactgular Sure, added it to the question

Comment: I found the issue. There was rogue node_modules directory somewhere on ../../../../../ (which was clearly in the error logs mentioned above, but didn't seem suspicious considering the nested nature of npm projects). I don't know why or how but this directory was scanned and spewed errors - this explains why the app was running fine.

Comment: Sometimes I feel I'm kind of an error-messages-blind person. It's in fact mentioned in the error message the problem was at the import statement.

Answer (score 2):

Few thing to check:

- Delete any package-lock.json or yarn-lock.json (Normally you install old version when you have this file, deleting it allows you to have a freshly installed package).
- Run `npm cache clean --force`.
- Delete node_modules folder.
- Run `npm i` again.

Comment: Followed these steps exactly, the result is the same. I discovered rxjs-compat was missing, but adding that package also didn't resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `node_modules` and try to run `npm install`.

```
npm uninstall --save rxjs
```

Then try this:

```
npm install --save rxjs
```

Comment: Deleting node_modules and doing a fresh npm install solved some random other (unrelated) warnings I had, but this error is still there.

Comment: @user1884155 See for changes.

Comment: Hmm, this didn't do anything.ItI uninstalled rxjs 6.3.5, then it installed it again, but the error persisted.